# Javascript redirection according to browser language

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to send visitors that have browser language in English to an alternative site.
I was able to find this code but it's not working:

```
<script type="type/javascript">

var language = navigator.browserLanguage;

// alert(language);

if (language.indexOf('en') > -1) {
document.location.href = 'http://en.socialpos.com.ar';
} else {
document.location.href = 'http://socialpos.com.ar';
}
</script>
```

I'm not even getting the alert :/
You can see it in http://socialpos.com.ar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var language = navigator.browserLanguage;
```

should be

```
var language = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage; //for IE
```

see my console results:

```
var language = navigator.browserLanguage;
undefined
language;
undefined
var language = navigator.language;
undefined
language;
"en-US"
```

Also please note that this was the first result for a google search: "javascript browser language". Google is your friend, and your google-fu is weak. Train it with searches!

Comment: `navigator.browserLanguage` is IE specific. you're better off using something like `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`

Comment: @zwacky ah I didn't know that, will append. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! The original script I got was old and based on Netscape. Editing it, I kept Netscape `navigator.browserLanguage` and deleted `navigator.language` Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

assuming your `alert(language)` wasn't commented out, your script tag should be

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script></script>
```

Comment: `<script></script>` is also fine

Comment: Thanks! I got this code from an old post that had `<script language="javascript">` and when editing it, that happened :)