# How do I automatic re-direct WebSite according to its region?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website,Now I have added 2 languages in it(English and German).

Now I want that when ever my website is open from Germany or any German user then it should open this site(https://splitscreenapp.com/de/)

And whenever it is open from any else user except German it should open this site(https://splitscreenapp.com)

Here below is one live example of the one website 
(https://neilpatel.com) When I open this website by using VPN and connecting to Germany then automatic this sites gets open and when I switch to any other location it opens in English language.

This is not a duplicate Question I don't want to change language setting from my browser it should automatically be redirected as per region.

I have tried implementing this code

```
<html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
         <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://splitscreenapp.com" />
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://splitscreenapp.com/de" />

        <link rel="canonical" href="https://splitscreenapp.com/de" />

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript redirection according to browser language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519370/javascript-redirection-according-to-browser-language)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. OP doesn't want to redirect based on language but on location.

Comment: "I don't want to change language setting from my browser it should automatically be redirected as per region." — That's a really bad idea. Trust that people have their browsers set to the language they want to read content in. Don't assume that a person's current geographical location represents the language they speak. It's a serious accessibility problem for tourists!

Comment: @Quentin I have written that I want it according to the region not as per users browser settings

Comment: @SarthakJoshi — Yes, you said you wanted it. I was criticising your desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the location using jquery and [ipapi](https://ipapi.co/). Then based on that you can redirect.

```
  function ipLookUp () {
  $.ajax('https://ipapi.co/json/')
  .then(
      function success(response) {
          if(response.country_name=='Germany')
          $(location).attr('href', 'https://splitscreenapp.com/de/');
      },

      function fail(data, status) {
          console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                      status);
      }
    );
  }
  ipLookUp()
```

Edit: The earlier api might give problems because it was not HTTPS. This API will send HTTPS requests.

Comment: But I want alternate links <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://splitscreenapp.com" />
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://splitscreenapp.com/de" />

Answer (score 1):

If your are using a backend on your project you can use this library to identify the country's IP:

https://www.ip2location.com/

But in your headers you should use **hreflang="x-default"** to identify where the user goes if the alterante language is not declared on the header.

Note that **canonical** "is a tool for showing search engines which version of a URL (each with the same content) is the dominant one to avoid duplicate content issues"

You shouldn't use canonical for different version based on language.

For more info ->

https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag

Comment: ** Note that making a Javascript redirection supose another jump on navigation, and is annoying for user and even can be decrease your SEO reputation